# Графические интерфейсы для разработки мобильных веб приложений

Tags: android, веб-программирование, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

1. Я слышал про Kotlin, Swift, но пока что не нашел в них способов создания графических пользовательских интерфейсов мобильных web приложений. Где они создаются?
2. Кроме Kotlin и Swift какие еще программы можно использовать для разработки мобильных web приложений? (нужен наиболее полный и подробный список, а также какие есть средства для разработки графического пользовательского интерфейса в этих программах)

P.S. Я имею ввиду под созданием интерфейсов - как в html : возможность использования button-ов, input-ов, textarea-ов, select-ов и других элементов. Есть такие возможности хоть где-то для мобильных устройств?

P.S.2 С помощью каких программ создаются пользовательский интерфейс для мобильных приложений (я нашел в инете пример - https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=swiftui, какие есть еще средства для создания приложений на Android и ioS)?

Comment: Мне кажется, здесь происходит терминологическая путаница. А на неправильное употребление терминов многие (в том числе и я) немедленно делаем стойку, как собачки. Не могли бы Вы объяснить, что такое, по вашему, "мобильные web приложения"? и чем они отличаются от не-мобильных? потому что мы (ну, абстрактные "мы", к которым я и себя отношу) довольно хорошо понимаем, что такое "web приложения" и что такое "мобильные приложения". А вот про то, что Вы спросили - есть сомнения...

Comment: О! Это - "интерфейс для мобильных приложений" - очень хорошее уточнение! Для созл\дания интерфейса мобильных приложений есть свои инструменты буквально в любой современной IDE: xCode, QT creator, Android Studio, Visual Studio - везде

Comment: S.H. Где в Kotlin находятся средства для создания пользовательского интерфейса? Где в Kotlin (а также в других языках программирования) можно создать элементы button, input, form для web приложения?

Comment: Думаю, Вам нужна Intelij IDEA - и гляньте вот этот ролик: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIdIXsi1qTU

Comment: @S.H. Огласите весь список пожалуйста.

Comment: В слдучае с Kotlin список довольно короткий, и я его уже огласил :-) В других IDE - другие языки. Хотя, так как Вы пишете на Kotlin _ скорее всего, Вы лучше знаете, в каких еще IDE есть его поддержка

Comment: @S.H. если вы обновите ответ (укажите всевозможные варианты создания графического пользовательского интерфейса), то я проголосую за ответ.

Comment: Хорошо, я через несколько часов добавлю в ответ картинок из разных IDE. прямо сейчас не могу - работа...

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, что под "способом создания графических интерфейсов мобильных web приложений" Вы понимаете способ, аналогичный "конструктору форм" в IDE для разработки WinForm приложений?

Тогда у меня для вас две новости.

Плохая: тот способ, которым долгое время пользовались для разработки WinForms - когда у вас есть "модель формы", и есть "палитра", и Вы мышкой перетаскиваете элементы с палитры на форму, выравниваете их там и т.п. - сейчас по каким то причинам не сильно популярен.

Причины тут простые: этот способ не очень хорошо подходит для WEBа. Там многое определяется CSS-ами, котрые применяются к набору элементов - в общем, есть сложности с этим способом.

А хорошая новость - что есть такая штука как Xamarin, в том числе - Xamarin forms. И эти штуки позволяют делать как "визуальное конструирование форм", так и мобильную разработку. И это - часть Visual Studio (настоящего, а не VS Code).

Правда, всё таки Xamarin - это не web. Это свой собственный набор базовых контролов, реализация которого есть для iOS и Android. А "бизнес-код" получается общий. Таким образом, реализуется голубая мечта всех программистов - "написано один раз, работает везде" (везде - это для iOS и Android).

Зато - это вполне себе полноценные мобильные приложения. Справедливости ради, надо сказать, что и у современного Flutter тоже свой набор контролов, и в чем то он очень похож на нативные контролы, а в чем то - отличается, и поэтому выгляит иногда немного чужеродным.

Comment: я имею ввиду под созданием интерфейсов - как в html : возможность использования button-ов, input-ов, textarea-ов, select-ов и других элементов. Есть такие возможности хоть где-то в программах для создания web-приложений для мобильных устройств?

Comment: Вот давайте вместе поразмышляем: web-приложения - это приложения, которые работают в барузере. "как в html : возможность использования button-ов, input-ов, textarea-ов, select-ов и других элементов" - в браузере есть. Вывод: "созданием интерфейсов мобильных web приложений" ничем, по большому счету, не отличается от создания интерфейсов НЕмобильных web приложений - это одно и то же! Браузер - он в очень большой степени одинаковый. Так что - лучше, еще раз объясните Ваш вопрос.

Comment: я уточнил вопрос (см. P.S.2).